# How to move a paragraph to the bottom of the page (without vspace)

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

I am looking to move a text paragraph of a few lines (like a disclaimer) at the bottom of a 2 page document. Each time I do that, I need to adjust that specific paragraph with the `\vspace` function.

Is there a function to put a paragraph directly at the bottom?

Comment: Did you try `vfill`? Can you post a minimal?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: You mean `\vfill`.

Answer (score 33):

If you want a more 'automated' approach, you could build an environment- it still uses `\vspace{\fill}` though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{bottompar}{\par\vspace*{\fill}}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{bottompar}
\lipsum[2]
\end{bottompar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unless you wanted the paragraph at the bottom of every page, like a footer?

Comment: This might not go at the bottom, if a page break occurs at the `\vspace`; probably it's better `\par\vspace*{\fill}`

Comment: Shouldn't you add a `\clearpage` instruction at the end of the `bottompage` environment -- just in case there's more text still to come, later on in the document?

Answer (score 17):

The TeX command `\vfill` may be what you're looking for, as used in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
abcdef
\vfill
ghijkl
\clearpage %force a page break
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\vfill` must have something before it on the page. If you want to have nothing at the top of the page, you can use `\null`.

Comment: @bebop - Your point is well taken. I thought that it was clear from the context of the OP's question that there would be something nontrivial on the page before `\vfill`. I suppose that's why I didn't point out this need explicitly. Nevertheless, it's worth stating it for the record. :-)